# Adding languages to gedit spellchecker

Tags: gedit

It's all in the title.

By language I mean human language that are not included in the default version (say dutch, german, spanish, ect...). I'm using gedit 3.4.x.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

I found an article that may be useful: https://help.gnome.org/users/gedit/stable/gedit-spellcheck.html.en

This states that you can Define the language to use for spell checking

By default, gedit will use your current language to spell check your document. If you need to use another language, choose Tools ▸ Set Language…, then choose the language you want to use.

EDIT: Sorry, I overlooked that a bit. I think you need to install dictionaries for them to show up in Tools > Set language menu I believe the languages will show up after you install the myspell-nl dictionary using System > Administration > Synaptic Package Manager

Comment: the question specifically asks for languages that are not one of the ones provided in the standards (stock) install of gedit. For example, think of a language that is not listed under tools->set language.

Comment: Sorry, I overlooked that a bit. I think you need to install dictionaries for them to show up in Tools > Set language menu

I believe the languages will show up after you install the myspell-nl dictionary using
System > Administration > Synaptic Package Manager

Comment: it worked! Can you add this to your answer?

Answer (score 6):

You can add a language, installing in your system the corresponding aspell library.

For instance, to install French language in Ubuntu, so that it appears in Gedit in the *Tools → Set Language* menu. Run this:

```
sudo apt-get install aspell-fr
```

([source](https://forums.linuxmint.com/viewtopic.php?t=72286))

After you do so, close Gedit and open it again

Comment: In my case it would be

 
    sudo apt install aspell-es

Comment: To get a list of available aspell packages: `apt search ^aspell-`